# My program does not write to PSQL via Sequelize

Tags: javascript, psql

```
/home/aam/exp/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:50
      throw new sequelizeError.ValidationError(null, this.errors);
            ^

ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: brand.name cannot be null
    at InstanceValidator._validate (/home/aam/exp/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:50:13)
    at async InstanceValidator._validateAndRunHooks (/home/aam/exp/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:60:7)
    at async InstanceValidator.validate (/home/aam/exp/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:54:12)
    at async model.save (/home/aam/exp/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2426:7)
    at async brand.create (/home/aam/exp/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1362:12)
    at async create (/home/aam/exp/server/controllers/brandController.js:7:21) {
  errors: [
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'brand.name cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'name',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: brand {
        dataValues: {
          id: null,
          name: undefined,
          updatedAt: 2023-08-11T12:17:58.885Z,
          createdAt: 2023-08-11T12:17:58.885Z
        },
        _previousDataValues: {},
        uniqno: 1,
        _changed: Set(0) {},
        _options: {
          isNewRecord: true,
          _schema: null,
          _schemaDelimiter: '',
          attributes: undefined,
          include: undefined,
          raw: undefined,
          silent: undefined
        },
        isNewRecord: true
      },
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
Node.js v18.17.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm writing my first app. It connects to the psql database. The get request works correctly. However, the server crashes when querying post. I assume that it is limited in writing to the database. Where can I dig?

To the base gave full access, I log in as root. Tried to change the port - did not help

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the psql command line tool.

Comment: I wonder if this needs to be retagged from `psql` to `postgresql`?

Comment: Your error is "brand.name cannot be null". That suggests that you are creating a row in the `brand` table, and the `name` column is being set as null (empty) but that is not permitted by a `NOT NULL`  constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details from the file in which you are calling the sequelize library I can't give you any exacts, but it would appear that you are initialising an instance of sequelize without providing a `brand.name` - as you can see from the error object, it cannot initialise as the current value is `null`.

Comment: Server started on port: 5000  
a get request to the same path yields
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "brands" AS "brand";

Comment: OK so what does your `update` or `insert` query look like?

Answer (score 0):

From the error its looking like in your model you have defined a constraint that brand name can't be null. `Like allowNull: false`. But when you calling the API you are not providing the name which means brand.name is null. So, you are violating that constraint. Try to provide the name in API's call in the body or remove the constraint from model.If you still facing the error you need to provide some more information about the error and post API call.

Answer (score 0):

The 'name' field cant be set to null according the the database schema but it is being set to 'null' in the query that you are providing and hence the error. Make sure to send valid data in the "POST" request and make sure that the 'name' field is not null.